# Hosting private and public websites on AWS S3

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have developed an Angular app with a flag which when set to `true` app works in a public mode (shows selected pages). I want to host my app as a static website on S3 bucket. So I have created two buckets

Bucket 1 - with flag set to false (private mode, unauthorized user can not access)

Bucket 2 - with flag set to true (public mode)

What I want to do is when a user tries to access my website with url like

`customdomain.co` - serve contents of private bucket (flag = `false`) and `customdomain.co/public` - serve the contents of my public S3 bucket (flag = `true`)

I have successfully set up a custom domain (eg. `customdomain.co`) and CloudFront distribution for my private static website. But I have no idea how can I set up the other url for public access using the same domain. Can anybody point me in right direction and tell me how can I achieve this? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use CloudFront as your reverse proxy to accomplish this similar to what is described here - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-amazon-cloudfront-application-router-chris-iona

Alternatively, you either need to use a sub domain instead (e.g. public.customdomain.co), reverse proxy the calls using API Gateway or another reverse proxy, or have a page at /public that does a redirect to the other site (which could be a sub domain).

Comment: Did this help answer your question?

Comment: thanks for reply. But my requirement is that I should be able to access another bucket using `customdomain.co/public`. I think I don't want to create a subdomain. Will creating multiple origins in a CloudFront distribution help? This way I can specify a `path` in behaviors to access public bucket?

Comment: That appears as though it may work since in this case CloudFront could be your reverse proxy. This link appears to detail what you'd like to do. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-amazon-cloudfront-application-router-chris-iona

Comment: Strange that the author of the post refers to path pattern matching as "basic regex," which it isn't.  It's a left-anchored, case-sensitive string match with `*` and `?` wildcards having their conventional wildcard meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Add the public bucket as a second origin on the CloudFront distribution.  Then, create a Cache Behavior matching the path pattern `/public*`, pointing to the new origin.

That's all that is necessary, except for one catch: the objects in the public bucket will need their keys to begin with `public/`, because CloudFront won't remove the prefix you matched in the path pattern.

If for some reason this constraint isn't acceptable, you will need a Lambda@Edge Origin Request trigger on the cache behavior, to rewrite the path before sending the request to the public bucket.